# Verifying Wallet Information

Tags: updates, 2.3-gingerbread, usb

I had my first Google play account for a little under a year and I made a few purchases and and long story short, those purchases got refunded so now my account won't let me buy anything without veryfying my wallet information. Well, I do not have that card anymore and I can't verify without it. I got a new phone and logged into my old account simply to link my contacts, pics, calendar info, etc. I then logged into my new account and tried to buy one small in-app purchase which was denied because my wallet info wasn't verified. I'm confused because this is a new account and I haven't bought anything so how could my wallet info need to be verified if their shouldn't be anything in the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to update your Google Play Account and remove the old credit card.  From your phone hit Google Play store app, go to your account, go add a payment method, or edit an existing one. Once there delete the old card and add the new one.